# Book about last human in the Galaxy, recovered from crashed ship

Tags: story-identification, novel

Human civilization has disappeared but human artifacts are highly sought after because they are so advanced they can give the species that found it an immense advantage over other species in the Galaxy.

One such artifact is found and the crew tries to take it to their home planet but are chased by those who want to possess it. Turns out the artifact is a cryo chamber with a human in it.

He wakes up, realizes he is the last known human alive and that he has slept for 10,000 years. Nevertheless he decides he now represents humanity and he should reassert human rule over the Galaxy by calling on humanity's client civilizations.

Most of the action takes place on a ship thats being pursued by others.

Book was written in the last 10 years. I think the name of the author is something starting with I or Y Not a common name, makes me think author might've been Asian but might be wrong...

Comment: I don't know the book but out of curiosity what is a "cryocamera"?

Comment: @organicMarble cryo chamber - he was injured in war and was frozen to be transported back for medical treatment but the ship was hit

Comment: @OrganicMarble, Modern English word `camera`(as the device that makes photos) is just clipping of `camera obscura`(*lit.* dark chamber), which was a primitive optical effect/device that led to developing of Photography. And in many other languages (that had latin/greek influence) `camera` kept `chamber` meaning.

Comment: I was hoping for some cool new device!  <== note use of "cool"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found it, it's Aer-ki Jyr's "Apex" . He is not Asian, apparently that's his "jedi name" ...

From the back cover:

> A new dawn is coming.
>
> It's been eons since Humans controlled the universe. Defeated by a
>   mysterious enemy, the downfall of Humanity brought about a virtual
>   dark age. Culture and technology stagnated in their absence. But now,
>   trade is once again flourishing as Human artifacts resurface
>   throughout the galaxy, resurrecting long forgotten advancements.
>
> And one such discovery might very well alter the course of the future
>   forever.
>
> An epic space adventure, Aer-ki Jyr's APEX is a breathless race to the
>   ultimate prize, with the very fate of the stars hanging in the
>   balance.

Comment: Please add details showing how it matches.

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised to find I own this as an ebook, it's in my TBR file.   I've had it almost two years so maybe I should get round to actually reading it at some point. (So many books and so little time!)